# Silverlight - I need to know Selected Text in a PasswordBox

Tags: silverlight, passwords, passwordbox, selectedtext

I'm building a complex change password form, but I need a simple task to continue my work:
I need to know what text is selected in a PasswordBox.
I know how to do it in TextBox components, using SelectedText, but I can't in a PasswordBox.

Have you some solutions to this problem?
Thank you

Comment: Pardon my curiosity, but why do you need such strange functionality?

Comment: @icebat I need to hook partial or complete paste in this field. So I'm having trouble to identify if text inside is completely, partially or not at all selected.

Comment: `PasswordBox` supports pasting out of box, partial too. Maybe you mean copying? That\`s not working for good security reasons, so I strongly suggest to leave it as it is.

Comment: There is no security issue in pasting inside a passwordBox. And this is not working only because Silverlight is a poor child of WPF. In WPF you can do this easily, because PasswordBox is derived from TextBox, but in Silverligth it is not.

Comment: I really mean "to paste". I need to know where the cursor is while the user is pasting and if passwordBox is selectedAll.